# JSON Array as List of Hash in Perl

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash

I'm very new to Perl, I have a non symmetric JSON array like below:

```
[
{"KEY1":"14507226013384557","KEY2":"1234","KEY3":"7899"},
{"KEY1":"14507226013384557","KEY2":"1234","KEY3":"7899","KEY4":"TEST","KEY5":"TEST1"},
{"KEY1":"14507226013384557","KEY2":"1234","KEY3":"7899","KEY5":"TEST New"},
]
```

I want to parse and store JSON array in a list of HASH, and then iterate that list of hash and check value of each KEYs and the process it. Any Idea how can I do ? I have used JSON decode and printed using dumper but I am facing issue while iterating through it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the Perl data structure that you got from Data::Dumper. It does not matter to your question that it came from JSON. You seem to know how to deserialize that, so that part is not relevant.

Comment: "list of HASH" -> "array of hash"

Answer (score 4):

```
my $data = decode_json($json_utf8);

for my $row (@$data) {
    for my $key (keys(%$row)) {
       say "$key: $row->{$key}";
    }

    say "";
}
```

References:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)